# Parsing JSON object from String

Tags: android, json, string

I am trying to parse the json object from the data at the end of the post using the following code but I seem to have problem converting the intial string to JSON and also extracting JSON object in the key values of "feed" and "entry".

```
protected void JSONparse(String result) {
    //parse JSON data
    try {
        JSONObject reader = new JSONObject(result);
        JSONObject head = reader.getJSONObject("feed").getJSONObject("entry").getJSONObject(result);
        JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(head);
        for(int i=0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject jObject = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
            String name = jObject.getString("name");
            String location = jObject.getString("location");
            String contact = jObject.getString("contact");
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, name+" "+location+" "+contact, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.show();

        } // End Loop

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSONException", "Error: " + e.toString());
    } // catch (JSONException e)

}
```

Data String:

```
{"version":"1.0","encoding":"UTF-8",
"feed":
{"xmlns":"http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom","xmlns$openSearch":"http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearchrss/1.0/","xmlns$gsx":"http://schemas.google.com/spreadsheets/2006/extended","id":{"$t":"https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/"key"/od6/public/values"},"updated":{"$t":"2018-09-17T01:06:22.497Z"},"category":[{"scheme":"http://schemas.google.com/spreadsheets/2006","term":"http://schemas.google.com/spreadsheets/2006#list"}],
"title":{"type":"text","$t":"Sheet1"},"link":[{"rel":"alternate","type":"application/atom+xml","href":"https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/"key"/pubhtml"},{"rel":"http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#feed","type":"application/atom+xml","href":"https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/"key"/od6/public/values"},{"rel":"http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#post","type":"application/atom+xml","href":"https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/"key"/od6/public/values"},
{"rel":"self","type":"application/atom+xml",
"href":"https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/"key"/od6/public/values?alt\u003djson"}],
"author":[{"name":{"$t":"appsmedion"},"email":{"$t":"appsmedion@gmail.com"}}],"openSearch$totalResults":{"$t":"6"},"openSearch$startIndex":{"$t":"1"},
"entry":
[{"id":{"$t":"https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/"key"/od6/public/values/cokwr"},
"updated":{"$t":"2018-09-17T01:06:22.497Z"},
"category":[{"scheme":"http://schemas.google.com/spreadsheets/2006",
"term":"http://schemas.google.com/spreadsheets/2006#list"}],
"title":{"type":"text","$t":"Chris knight "},
"content":{"type":"text","$t":"location: Crows Nest NSW, type: dji, contact: na"},
"link":[{"rel":"self","type":"application/atom+xml",
"href":"https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/"key"/od6/public/values/cokwr"}],"gsx$name":{"$t":"Chris knight "},"gsx$location":{"$t":"Crows Nest NSW"},"gsx$type":{"$t":"dji"},
"gsx$contact":{"$t":"na"}},{"id":{"$t":"https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/"key"/od6/public/values/cpzh4"},"updated":{"$t":"2018-09-17T01:06:22.497Z"},"category":[{"scheme":"http://schemas.google.com/spreadsheets/2006","term":"http://schemas.google.com/spreadsheets/2006#list"}],"title":{"type":"text","$t":"Shayne Johnston"},"content":{"type":"text","$t":"location: Hay Nsw , type: dji, contact: 466863944"},"link":[{"rel":"self","type":"application/atom+xml","href":"https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/"key"/od6/public/values/cpzh4"}],"gsx$name":{"$t":"Shayne Johnston"},"gsx$location":{"$t":"Hay Nsw "},"gsx$type":{"$t":"dji"},"gsx$contact":{"$t":"466863944"}},{"id":{"$t":"https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/"key"/od6/public/values/cre1l"},"updated":{"$t":"2018-09-17T01:06:22.497Z"},"category":[{"scheme":"http://schemas.google.com/spreadsheets/2006","term":"http://schemas.google.com/spreadsheets/2006#list"}],"title":{"type":"text","$t":"Edward Morris"},"content":{"type":"text","$t":"location: Alkimos WA, type: dji, contact: edwardcmorris@yahoo.com.au"},"link":[{"rel":"self","type":"application/atom+xml","href":"https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/"key"/od6/public/values/cre1l"}],"gsx$name":{"$t":"Edward Morris"},"gsx$location":{"$t":"Alkimos WA"},"gsx$type":{"$t":"dji"},"gsx$contact":{"$t":"edwardcmorris@yahoo.com.au"}},{"id":{"$t":"https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/"key"/od6/public/values/chk2m"},"updated":{"$t":"2018-09-17T01:06:22.497Z"},"category":[{"scheme":"http://schemas.google.com/spreadsheets/2006","term":"http://schemas.google.com/spreadsheets/2006#list"}],"title":{"type":"text","$t":"Andy"},"content":{"type":"text","$t":"location: Wellington St Mulgrave VIC, type: dji, contact: 413556955"},"link":[{"rel":"self","type":"application/atom+xml","href":"https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/"key"/od6/public/values/chk2m"}],"gsx$name":{"$t":"Andy"},"gsx$location":{"$t":"Wellington St Mulgrave VIC"},"gsx$type":{"$t":"dji"},"gsx$contact":{"$t":"413556955"}},{"id":{"$t":"https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/"key"/od6/public/values/ciyn3"},"updated":{"$t":"2018-09-17T01:06:22.497Z"},"category":[{"scheme":"http://schemas.google.com/spreadsheets/2006","term":"http://schemas.google.com/spreadsheets/2006#list"}],"title":{"type":"text","$t":"Cody"},"content":{"type":"text","$t":"location: Alice Spring NT, type: parrot, contact: 412222222"},"link":[{"rel":"self","type":"application/atom+xml","href":"https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/"key"/od6/public/values/ciyn3"}],"gsx$name":{"$t":"Cody"},"gsx$location":{"$t":"Alice Spring NT"},"gsx$type":{"$t":"parrot"},"gsx$contact":{"$t":"412222222"}},{"id":{"$t":"https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/"key"/od6/public/values/ckd7g"},"updated":{"$t":"2018-09-17T01:06:22.497Z"},"category":[{"scheme":"http://schemas.google.com/spreadsheets/2006","term":"http://schemas.google.com/spreadsheets/2006#list"}],"title":{"type":"text","$t":"Anthony "},"content":{"type":"text","$t":"location: Bundaberg , type: dji, contact: anthonycarrick1978@yahoo.com.au"},"link":[{"rel":"self","type":"application/atom+xml","href":"https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/"key"/od6/public/values/ckd7g"}],"gsx$name":{"$t":"Anthony "},"gsx$location":{"$t":"Bundaberg "},"gsx$type":{"$t":"dji"},"gsx$contact":{"$t":"anthonycarrick1978@yahoo.com.au"}}]}}
```

Comment: `Invalid JSON variable`

Comment: is json is valid? tested on JSONLint?

Comment: your JSON is invalid. So it is not the JSON. You should fix your JSON first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like JSON is incorrect. 
Even if JSON would be correct - "entry" is an array, not an object. Try this code:

```
protected void JSONparse(String result) {
    //parse JSON data
    try {
        JSONObject reader = new JSONObject(result);
        JSONArray jArray = reader.getJSONObject("feed").getJSONArray("entry");
        for(int i=0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject jObject = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
            String name = jObject.getString("gsx$name");
            String location = jObject.getString("gsx$location");
            String contact = jObject.getString("gsx$contact");
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, name+" "+location+" "+contact, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.show();

        } // End Loop

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSONException", "Error: " + e.toString());
    } // catch (JSONException e)

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to fix your json string first.

Easiest ways to do it is web pages like https://jsoneditoronline.org/ ...

Or simply create your_file_name.json file in Android studio and let lint to show you where error or errors is.